# How to correct this mouse click error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, zelle-graphics

My program is a stop watch, and basically, when you click `stopImage` it should stop at the time it was at. However, I'm not sure how to get it to do that without resetting the clock. Also, if I click outside the `startImage` button twice, the clock starts, and if I then click `stopImage`, it resets to zero. The graphics package I'm using is [Zelle's graphics](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python).

```
from graphics import *
import time

win = GraphWin('Stopwatch', 600, 600)
win.yUp()

timer = Text(Point(300, 260), '')
timer.setSize(30)
timer.draw(win)
timer.setText('00:00:00')

stopWatchImage = Image(Point (300, 300), "stopwatch.png")
startImage = Image(Point (210, 170), "startbutton.png")
stopImage = Image(Point (390, 170), "stopbutton.png")
lapImage = Image(Point (300, 110), "lapbutton.png")
stopWatchImage.draw(win)
startImage.draw(win)
stopImage.draw(win)
lapImage.draw(win)

def pressed(pt, image):
    width = image.getWidth()
    height = image.getHeight()
    anchor = image.getAnchor()
    x1 = (anchor.getX()) - (.5 * width)
    x2 = (anchor.getX()) + (.5 * width)
    y1 = (anchor.getY()) - (.5 * height)
    y2 = (anchor.getY()) + (.5 * height)
    return(x1 <= pt.getX() <= x2 and y1 <= pt.getY() <= y2)

def timeFormat():
    sec = 0
    minute = 0
    hour = 0
    timeDisplay = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}".format(hour, minute, sec)
    timer.setText(timeDisplay)
    check = win.getMouse()
    task = 'start'
    '''
    if pressed(check, startImage):
        task = 'start'
    '''
    while task == 'start':
        task = 'start'
        time.sleep(1)
        sec += 1
        if sec == 60:
            sec = 0
            minute += 1
        if minute == 60:
            sec = 0
            minute = 0
            hour += 1
        timeDisplay = "{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}".format(hour, minute, sec)
        timer.setText(timeDisplay)
        check = win.checkMouse()
        if check != None:
            if pressed(check, stopImage):
                task = 'stop'
                print('stoppressed')
                main()
                '''
                if pressed(check, startImage):
                    task = 'start'
                    print('start2pressed')
                    timeFormat()
                '''
            if pressed(check, lapImage):
                sec = 0
                minute = 0
                hour = 0
                task = 'stop'
                timer.setText('00:00:00')
                print('lappressed')
                timeFormat()

def main():
    check = win.checkMouse()
    if check!= None:
        while not pressed(win.checkMouse(), startImage):
            continue

    timeFormat()

main()
```

Comment: BTW, it's generally _not_ a good idea to call `time.sleep` in GUI code because that blocks the GUI from updating itself or checking for pending events. Instead, you need to use an appropriate time delay  method provided by the GUI framework.

Comment: Sorry about that @PM2Ring, I am using Zelle's graphics.

Comment: @PM2Ring , I have updated my code so that it is runnable. Please keep in mind that the images are custom images I made so I'm not sure you will be able to run it. If you really want the images to run it and there is some way I can give them to you, feel free to let me know.

Comment: That's much better! It _is_ possible to upload images to Stack Overflow, but that's probably not necessary, since generic image files can easily be substituted for your custom images.

Comment: @PM2Ring Good point, thanks for taking the time to check my code and comment man.

Comment: No worries. I've made a few minor improvements to your question. Sorry I can't answer your question: I've never used Zelle's graphics module myself, but hopefully you'll get someone with the appropriate expertise now that your question has the zelle-graphics tag.

Comment: zelle-graphics uses `tkinter` in background which have function `after(miliseconds, function_name)` and it can be use to execute function periodically and update time - instead of `sleep` and `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you @furas, I will remember that for next time I make something like this.

Comment: Regarding your deleted question, the downvotes are likely because the question was off-topic based on the Stack Overflow guidelines. [Read the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) when you get a moment, the material there is very good!